Torrent client with a feature to export data
Name any torrent client for Windows or Linux that can export data about torrents, at least name, ratio and seeding time, to any format (like CSV or XML).
The end purpose is to sort torrents by popularity (ratio divided by seeding time). But I want be able to make any custom sorting/filtering of these data in table processors or databases.
Select all the table (torrents are normally shown in a table view in clients) and copy to some other program is also ok.
